# Javascript for loop with object instead of counter?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Looking at this piece of code:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = families[i]; i++) {
}
```

I haven't actually seen a loop like this before and I want to be sure I understand it correctly.
Am I correct in assuming that if `families.length == 2` that the 2nd part of the `for` line would return false on `f = families[2]`?

I would have thought it would need to be something like `f == families[2]` in order to return false.

Comment: I'm intrigued, I assume that the loop won't stop till a certain criteria is met, not exactly when you process all the entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f = families[i]` is an expression that returns the value of `families[i]`. (It also has the side-effect of assigning that value to `f`)

If `families.length === 2` then `families[2] === undefined` thus the expression returns `undefined` which is falsey and breaks the loop.

For more hacking fun you can turn

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = families[i]; i++) {
  // body
}
```

into

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = families[i++]; /* body */);
```

You may have to string replace `;` with `,` and string replace `i` with `i-1`. You also just murdered readability.

It should also be pointed out that the for loop is silly for readability.

```
Object.keys(families).forEach(function(key) {
  var family = families[key];
  /* body */
});
```

Is significantly more readable.

Comment: *You also just murdered readability.* Heh heh. Colonel Mustard in the observatory with the keyboard.

Comment: Indeed, but also per LEOPiC's comment, it's also possible that a falsey value somewhere in the middle of the array would cause the loop to break, not always necessarily when you hit the end...

Comment: @Funka since when is a `family` falsey ;)

Comment: The last example is not semantically the same; families could have additional properties attached (or not be a "real array"). But otherwise, +1.

Comment: @pst any competent programmer would make those additional properties non enumerable ;)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like kind of a silly way of doing

```
for(var i in families) {
    if (families.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // do whatever you want with families[i]
        console.log(families[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't make sense to me.  Why use this versus a regular for loop?  To me, the loop I posted is essentially taking out a line from a regular for loop where I would instantly say something like `var family = families[i];`

Comment: This is different ... families could have properties that are not 0..n, even if "own".